# JavaScript making users click before executing next action

Tags: javascript, jquery

We do currently have a button which does send an action to an API. This is a giveaway app. What I want to achieve: We have multiple sponsors in the database. (Multiple links). The button should be only available, if each link is clicked.

How am I able to do this with multiple links? I've thought about it when we had like one link, we could set a variable to true. How are we able to do this with multiple ones?

Comment: Just set a value to `true` once all links have been clicked? Setting a `clicked` value for each of the links?

Comment: do you have some sample code?

Comment: Sample code not yet, I'm searching for an option to do it. So you'd say something like checking all link classes (like link-sponsor) and adding another class or data-value for it once it's clicked? That's a nice idea, thank you.

Comment: Idea 1 : Use a hashMap {link} = boolean (isClicked) and check if all values are at true

Comment: Idea 2 : Add a char to a string each time a link is clicked (one char by link), then remove all duplicate chars, order the result and check if it is equal to "abcdef" by example. This way seems weird, but quite fun :)

Comment: Idea 3 : Use an array. You push the clicked link in the array, remove duplicate and check the array length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd handle it.

First, assign each link a unique class. Then create an array that contains the classes for each link you wish to be clicked. Then you can check if each of these links have been clicked by checking if their class is in the respective array:

```js
var required_links = ["one", "two", "three"];
var count = 0;

$(document).on("click", ".link", function() {
  if ($.inArray(this.classList[1], required_links) != -1 && !$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    console.log("User clicked link '" + this.classList[1] + "' for the first time.");
    count++;
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
  }
  if (count == required_links.length) {
    console.log("All links clicked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="link one">Link 1</div>
<div class="link two">Link 2</div>
<div class="link three">Link 3</div>
```

In the above snippet, I'm checking for the presence of the `clicked` class. Once clicked, the element has the class added, so it can't be clicked again. This ensures that you have to click **each** link, rather than simply being able to click the same element multiple times.

Note that I'm using `<div>` tags in the above example, but the same theory will work by simply affixing the relevant classes to the `<a>` tag instead.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I know you might not need another solution, but this might be a little easier to maintain based off of how many links you have. You can have as many links as you want, just make sure they have a `class="required"`.

As you click on each link, that class is removed. Once there are no more links with `class="required"`, the button/link becomes clickable.

```js
$(function() {
 $( ".required" ).click(function() {
     $(this).removeClass("required");
        if ($( ".required" ).length == 0) {
         $( "button" ).prop("disabled", false);
         $( "button" ).text("Well maybe now you can.");
        }
    });

 $( "button" ).click(function() {
     // second check to deter the tricksters
     if ($( ".required" ).length == 0) {
         window.location.href = "http://www.gosomewherecool.com/"
        }
    });
})
```

```css
.required {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="required"> You gotta click me! </a> <br>
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="required"> Oh and me! </a> <br>
<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" class="required"> Me too! </a> <br>

<button disabled>
Can't click me yet!
</button>
```

Comment: This makes it alot easier. Thank you for the suggestion.